# ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.7 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: ssh

I get this error when ever I try to connect my desktop with another desktop using SSH, but I'm able to ping the other desktop successfully.

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.7 port 22: Connection refused
```

I can connect to remote server using SSH but I'm not able to connect within the local network.
Please help me in this regards,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The Connection Refused message generally means there is nothing listening on the relevant port. Make sure that sshd is running.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your SSH daemon is not running..

Comment: When I do ps -ef |grep ssh I get the pid no with it

Comment: service sshd status run this command and let us know what outout you are getting.

Comment: can run below two command and see if your ssh works or not , If you are on RPM based then 1. service iptables stop 2. set enforce 0 or if you are on debian based try to stop apparmor service apparmor stop.

Answer (score 0):

Either not running, or blocked by some firewall or not listening on that interface/IP...

Comment: Firewall blocking does not generate connection refused error.

Comment: @Khaled it does if you `REJECT` rather than `DROP`.